# Keep running python even though exit code

Tags: python, python-2.7, exit-code

I am calling an external program from python 2.7 and as an input to that program I have a few parameters. I do not have access to the code of the program that I am calling. For some combinations of these parameters the program crashes and returns an exit code, and no error; typically "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)". What I want to do is: whenever it fails with this exit code I want it to rerun the script with new initial parameters. I tried something along:

```
parameters1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
parameters2 = [2, 3, 4, 5]
j = 0
q = 0
while j == 0:
    parameter1 = parameters1[q]
    parameter2 = parameters2[q]
    try:
        f3d.run(parameter1 = parameter1, parameter2 = parameter2)
        j = 1
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: It's unclear where you are running the external program. `f3d.run` is still a call to a Python function.

Comment: You should also include the (full) error into your question.

Comment: `try`-`except: pass` tends to be a really bad thing to do: it ignores each and every error, and doesn't handle them. Errors are actually a good thing, but with a try-except: pass block, you turn them into bugs (your program/data fails, but no-one will know about it).

Comment: There are a number of questions that are about this error message (they are easy to search for); all seem to be related to PyCharm, and occasionally re-installing will help. Are you using PyCharm?

Comment: "I tried something along:" Okay, and *what happened* when you tried that? What is supposed to happen instead, and how is that different?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is *not a discussion forum*; we don't care that you're a beginner (we would be able to tell without you saying it, after all; if we couldn't, that would already make you not a beginner) and we don't care about your guesses about whether the question has been asked before (if it has, generally your question gets closed with a link to the previous one; it's a good idea to try to find it yourself first). We do care about *your question*, being asked per the guidelines in [ask].

Comment: (Even on actual discussion forums, any time you want to say "sorry if I'm <doing X>", it would be a hundred times better to *try to figure out whether you actually are <doing X>*, try to figure out whether the community is okay with that, and if not, try to avoid it.)

Answer (score 0):

While the question is quite unclear, I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

runner.py:

```
SLEEP_TIME = 3
print('Starting run...')

while True:

    exit_code = subprocess.call(['python', 'foo.py', parameter_1, parameter_2])
    print('Script Stopped.')

    if exit_code == -1073741819:
        # change parameter_1 and parameter_2 here

    print('Sleeping for %d seconds' % SLEEP_TIME)
    time.sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    print('Restarting...')
```

foo.py:

```
import sys
parameter_1 = sys.argv[1]
parameter_2 = sys.argv[2]

# Your code here
```

You run the `runner.py` which will keep restarting infinitely.

Also, unwanted advice: Do not use Python2.7. Its outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the fast and good answer! This is what I was looking for.
I had to use Python2.7 to be compatible with the external software.
Have a nice day my good sir/madam!

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.